# Text is appearing blurry as you get further into the report

Tags: pdf.js

We have some reports generated with *JasperReports 6.2.0* that have this bizarre affect where as you get further into pages of the report the text gets more blurry as you go. The first page or two is crisp text, but get to page 30 or so and it becomes unreadable. In our scenario we are printing checks, so I can only post close up shots of some text. But the first image is the first page, and the second image is about page 28. Notice the difference.

We have two font extensions set up with Calibri and MICR fonts, They are added correctly and have the pdfEncoding set to Cp1250 and pdfEmbedded to true (I have tried other values).

How can we make the text not become blurry? Thanks

[image: First Page]

[image: Page 28]

UPDATE: I am removing Jasper Reports from the equation/cause of the issue. And believe it might be in the component PDF.js that we are using that renders the PDF into the print preview.

Comment: Do you have the same effect in pdf file? It looks like a magic or a problem with a printer (the ink is low, for example)

Comment: The screenshots where for the exact same report. Page 1 versus page 28 of a 30 page jasper report. And this happens with our other reports too. The printer has plenty of ink. Thanks Alex.

Comment: To add to my comment. This happens on more than one printer even different types. We have about 10 different customers printing checks with different printers and all have the same affect. This report also does not generate a PDF, so to speak, We generate the report and it immediately opens up a print dialog for them to print. In that screen it also shows a preview of it, and the screenshots are from the preview screen, but are very accurate representations of how it actually prints too. Thanks Alex K.

Comment: You can also use some virtual printer for check, I think

Comment: Thanks Alex K for all your comments and help I appreciate it very much. And unfortunately it is on other reports too, not just the checks. And the whole legal stuff. Anyway, some on our team have narrowed things down a bit, and we believe Jasper Reports is probably not the cause, but our PDF viewer renderer for printing. I am updating the post.

Comment: It is a good news for JR's fans.  Good luck )